# Unknown service: 'batch' using boto3 in python3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I'm receiving this error trying to use AWS Batch with boto3:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'batch'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, autoscaling, budgets, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, config, datapipeline, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dms, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, gamelift, glacier, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, kinesis, kinesisanalytics, kms, lambda, logs, machinelearning, marketplacecommerceanalytics, meteringmarketplace, opsworks, rds, redshift, route53, route53domains, s3, sdb, servicecatalog, ses, sms, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, waf, workspaces
```

The error is easily reproducible:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> batch = boto3.client('batch')
```

Checking my boto3 and botocore versions:

```
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.4.8'
>>> import botocore
>>> botocore.__version__
'1.4.70'
```

I'm assuming my system is somehow misconfigured. Can anyone guess what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your botocore didn't get upgraded. What do you get for:

```
import botocore
botocore.__version__
```

You can upgrade botocore by:

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
```

Comment: Good thought, though I had previously tried updating botocore to no avail. I've included my botocore version in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'bedrock'. Valid service names are: ...
```

I tried creating a virtual environment and installing the required .whl files for it, which are downloaded from

Step 1: https://d2eo22ngex1n9g.cloudfront.net/Documentation/SDK/bedrock-python-sdk.zip

Step2: Unzip the SDK archive to access the .whl files.

Step3: **cd  Path :>**
python3 -m pip install botocore-1.31.21-py3-none-any.whl

**cd  Path :>**  python3 -m pip install boto3-1.28.21-py3-none-any.whl

**cd  Path :>** python3 -m pip install awscli-1.29.21-py3-none-any.whl

Finally, it worked.